# While loop to wait contact is updated status

Tags: javascript, automation, testcafe

I'm using testcafe for automation in my product, right now we have flow to retry to update the contact in 5 times in each time will be 1 minuted.
I have idea that will create white loop for this to wait refresh page until the contact is updated to expected status

```
    while(!statusExpect.existed){

        await refreshPage()
    }
```

But saw that not run with my expected, have any issued for that function ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) We can't help you without more information, but in general, polling like this is poor practice. Instead, have the update process provide some form of notification it's done.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have in mind ?

```
int retryCount    = 0;
boolean isUpdated = false;

while (retryCount < 5 && !isUpdated) {
    try {
         // your code to update the contact here
        isUpdated = true; // set to true if update is successful
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Update failed, retrying in 1 minute...");
        Thread.sleep(60000); // sleep for 1 minute before retrying
        retryCount++;
    }
}

if (!isUpdated) {
    System.out.println("Failed to update contact after 5 attempts");
}
```

Comment: Update the contact is running in the backgroud, so i think need to wait the status is updated in each time

Comment: If the contact is being updated in the background, you may need to wait for the status to be updated before you can access the latest information.
If the application or service provides an API for accessing contact information, you may be able to use a webhook or other real-time notification mechanism to receive updates when a contact's information changes. This can help you keep your application's information up-to-date without needing to constantly poll for updates.

Comment: Yes but running in background we have retry to update status, it max 5 times but we don't know that time is success, so i think we need while loop in here and each 1 minute will refresh page to verify status is updated or not